# Odoo migration from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, migration, odoo

We have Odoo v8 installed on Linux Ubuntu, the server is going to be dismissed soon. 
I have dumped the database from db managment but i also have to save all files from LINUX because some of them are customized then copy in a local windows machine, is that possible? 
which is the best way to go?

I have access to the dedicated server (ubuntu)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Would you please edit your question with your attempts.

Comment: I have been able to export the db from ubuntu then installed odoo v8 in w7 machine but it wont run when launched > localhost:5432,totally new with Odoo, no experience, excuse me.

Comment: can you try with localhost:8069 ?

Comment: Sure but i get 500 Internal Server Error. I haven't installed pyton or anything, just the odoo installer from here: https://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/exe/odoo_8.0.latest.exe

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pVdANsRq error log

Comment: Isn't 5432 the port for PostgreSQL ? Is your PostgreSQL currently running ?

Comment: Error log confirms the issue is that PostgreSQL is either not running or is misconfigured (or blocked by firewall, or ...). You should install it and try again. If it still fails, then you should ask https://superuser.com/ for help about this.